# What do the different actions of the OpenAI gym's environment of 'Pong-v0' represent?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, environment, gym, action-spaces

Printing `action_space` for Pong-v0 gives `Discrete(6)` as output, i.e. $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ are actions defined in the environment as per the documentation. However, the game needs only 2 controls. Why do we have this discrepancy? Further, is that necessary to identify which number from 0 to 5 corresponds to which action in a gym environment?

Comment: Programming questions (including how to use a certain library or API) are off-topic here. This type of question is more appropriate for Stack Overflow, even though the question is still related to Artificial Intelligence/Reinforcement Learning. Here, we focus on the theoretical, social, and philosophical aspects of AI. Please, see https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details.

Answer (score 8):

You can try the actions yourselves, but if you want another reference, [check out the documentation for ALE at GitHub](https://github.com/openai/atari-py/blob/master/doc/manual/manual.pdf).

In particular, 0 means no action, 1 means fire, which is why they don't have an effect on the racket.

Here's a better way:

```
env.unwrapped.get_action_meanings()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try to figure out what exactly does an action do using such script:

```
action = 0  # modify this!
o = env.reset()
for i in xrange(5): # repeat one action for five times
    o = env.step(action)[0]
IPython.display.display(
    Image.fromarray(
        o[:,140:142]  # extract your bat
    ).resize((300, 300))  # bigger image, easy for visualization
)
```

`action` 0 and 1 seems useless, as nothing happens to the racket.

`action` 2 & 4 makes the racket go up, and `action` 3 & 5 makes the racket go down.

The interesting part is, when I run the script above for the same `action`(from 2 to 5) two times, I have different results. Sometimes the racket reaches the top(bottom) border, and sometimes it doesn't. I think there might be some randomness on the speed of the racket, so it might be hard to measure which type of UP(2 or 4) is faster.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be no difference between 2 & 4 and 3 & 5. The inconsistency mentioned by Icyblade is due to the mechanics of the Pong environment.

"Each action is repeatedly performed for a duration of k frames, where k is uniformly sampled from {2,3,4}"

So the action is just repeated a different number of times due to randomness